# Where to get replacement bolt for rod brakes

Tags: brakes, repair, vintage

Well, I did it again: While working on a bike with rod brakes I lost the bolt which connects the two "actuating" rods to each other (I have no idea what these parts are even called; The measuring tape is in centimeters):

[image: Rod with bolt][image: Rod without bolt]

Here are the nuts securing the thing:
[image: Nuts]

Where on Earth can I get something like this?-- is this even possible, or did I just ruin my last bike purchase in a record two weeks?

Comment: You should be able to simply find a bolt that fits though that hole and drill a smaller hole through it to accept the smaller rod. The position will be important and you may have to have a couple of attempts. Finding antique parts is hard, and you should adjust your work habits so you don't lose the parts. Working on a tarp or sheet of plastic, for example,may help.

Comment: You've still got the other one - take it to a nut and bolt specialist and ask for help.   Consider buying a jar of a hundred rather than one, you'll use them again if they're vaguely normal.   Or buy some threadded rod and use a drill press to fabricate your own parts - this is rewarding, albeit expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's an adjustment nut of rod brake.

[image: Image from http://threespeedhub.com/]

Not trying to recommend a product but if you search for rod brake nut, and look for something with this similar shape, you will find them being sold on-line (still).

http://www.highnelly.ie/brake-parts/rod-brake-lock-nut.html

Comment: That basic style of bolt is a more-or-less (mostly less) "standard" hardware item.  Similar bolts are used, eg, to fasten fender stays.  And, worst case, one could get a standard bolt and drill a hole in it.

Answer (score 2):

Not trying to be over simplistic but did you try your local hardware store? If I'm understanding right you've lost a bolt to a nut and bolt combination. Take what you do have and go to the hardware store to replace. Might be a bit shiny but it can get you functionality.

FYI, this isn't a "I told you so" but is meant as help. Consider getting an old dozen egg crate or pie tin to work out of. A clean shop rag underneath keeps things from slipping. Separate parts from tools when working a bench.

Last, agreed with Nhan Le, excellent idea going to the web. Can't directly mention source respecting board rules but just like vintage car parts there are retrofit vintage bike parts available from the bulk bike part distributors. I was surprised what I found for a Strumy Archer 3 speed shifter assembly I worked on last season. Whole assembly, shifter, housing, cable, linkage. Old can be cool but it can get rusty too, which inhibits functionality.

Bests, all~

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but is that an Imperial or metric piece?-- it's from an old Raleigh and I live in a country where x/y-inch stuff isn't sold... Hence my panic.

Comment: Metal muffin trays work really well.  Mine's got a dozen bowls, and each has a small magnet glued to the bottom side to restrain metal things.  I've flipped the whole tray over at least once and the only things that fell off were non-ferrous parts, either plastic or aluminium.  Numbering the bowls works well too - reassemble in reverse order.